# phonegap app for ipad and ipad mini

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am making app for ipad and ipad mini . I am new to phonegap and have some basic knowledge about html css  . I am stuck with the image proportion , width and height of the app .

I want to make it generalize code so it will work ok with height and width of ipad mini . any starter link or help will be apreciated .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

iPad (1 and 2), iPad retina (3 and 4) and iPad mini have the same logical pixels, and that is what matters on the css, so you don't have to worry about the phisical pixels, the same app will look the same on all the iPads.
Nevertheless you should look info about RWD (Responsive web design), it can help you if you decide to port the iPad app to android.

Comment: thanks for the reply so if i give some pixel value like padding-left:20px it will not effect the whole layout when user see it on ipad mini ?

Comment: no, he will see the same that other user with an iPad or iPad retina , but he will see it smaller because the screen is smaller, everything is smaller, but with the same proportions.